# How to interpret the regular condition in this theorem about cones in convex analysis?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Theorem:Let $K_1,\dots, K_m$ be convex cones in $R^n$ and let $K = K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \dots K_m$. If $K_1 \cap int(K_2) \cap \dots \cap int(K_m) \neq \emptyset$(regularity assumption), then $K^\circ = K_1^\circ + \dots + K_m^\circ$.

My question is why do we call the assumption regular? If it doesn't hold, $K$ could still be a nonempty convex cone I think. Or put it another way, what happens if $K \neq \emptyset$ but $K_1 \cap int(K_2) \dots \cap int(K_m) = \emptyset$? Why is this case irregular? Is it trivial?

I don't if I am in the right direction, but I'll put my thought here. If regular assumption doesn't hold, then $int(K) = \emptyset$, then $K$ must be contained in a lower dimension linear manifold(or affine set if you will). But even regular assumption holds, $int(K)$ could still be empty, since we can make $int(K_1) = \emptyset$. So I am not sure why we distinguish these two cases. Just for the theorem holds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the regularity, otherwise the theorem may fail. It is quite insightful if you try to construct counterexamples.

If all $K_i$ are also closed, you have
$$K^\circ = \operatorname{cl}(K_1^\circ + \ldots +K_m^\circ)$$
without further assumptions. It also helps to construct examples where the closure on the right-hand side is needed.